# Extract string after last match strings

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery and I want to extract string after the specific match strings, in my case, the strings is `sc`

I have a string like this :

```
www.xxss.com?psct=T-EST2%20.coms&.com/u[sc'sc(mascscin', sc'.c(scscossccnfiscg.scjs']-/ci=1(sctitis)
```

My expected result is:

```
titis)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which dbms is used?

Comment: You should also post your attempted SQL script, it will help us to provide more context in our responses

Comment: Hi, sorry i forgot to type my database. Im using bigquery for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, across all RDBMS finding the index of the *last* instance of a match in a string is easy to compute by first reversing the string. Then we are only looking for the *first* match.

### Update: BigQuery

> Follow the documentation for `REGEXP_EXTRACT` in the [String Functions documentation for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract)
>
> > ***NOTE:*** BigQuery provides regular expression support using the [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) library; see that documentation for its regular expression syntax.

However, this problem can be solved without RegEx.

BigQuery supports array processing and has a `SPLIT` function, so you could split by the lookup variable and capture only the last result:

```
SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(  !YOUR COLUMN HERE!  , "sc"))[OFFSET(1)]
```

The following adaptation from my original submission may still work:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(@text), 1, STRPOS(REVERSE(@text), "cs") -1))
```

---

For those who have a similar requirement in MS SQL Server the following syntax can be used.
*other RDBMS can use a similar query, you will have to use the appropriate platform functions to acheive the result.*

```
DECLARE @text varchar(200) = 'www.xxss.com?psct=T-EST2%20.coms&.com/u[sc''sc(mascscin'', sc''.c(scscossccnfiscg.scjs'']-/ci=1(sctitis)'
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@text), CharIndex('cs', REVERSE(@text),1) -1))
```

Produces: `titis)`

> You could achieve a similar result by obtaining the last *index* of 'sc' as above and using that value in a `SUBSTRING` however for that to work you need to re-compute the Length, this solution instead uses the `LEFT` function and then `REVERSE`'s the result , reducing the functional complexity of the query by 1 (1 less function call)

---

Step this through:

1. Reverse the value:

   ```
    SELECT REVERSE(@text)
   ```

   Results in:

   ```
    )sititcs(1=ic/-]'sjcs.gcsifnccssocscs(c.'cs ,'nicscsam(cs'cs[u/moc.&smoc.02%2TSE-T=tcsp?moc.ssxx.www
   ```
2. Now we find the *first* Index of `'cs'`
   ***Note:** we have to reverse the sequece of the lookup string as well!*

   ```
    SELECT CharIndex('cs', REVERSE(@text),1)
   ```

   Result: 7
3. Select the characters before this index:
   ***Note:** we must use `-1` here because SQL uses 1-based index result from CharIndex so we must reduce it by 1*

   ```
    SELECT LEFT(REVERSE(@text), CharIndex('cs', REVERSE(@text),1) -1)
   ```
4. Finally, we reverse the result:

   ```
    SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@text), CharIndex('cs', REVERSE(@text),1) -1))
   ```

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for your answer, can i use this for bigquery standard sql ? Sorry i forget to give my db information

Comment: Updated for BigQuery

Comment: Also added a BigQuery adaptation of my original solution

Answer (score -2):

Guess you could use 'sc' as seperator, define (if constant string length) string length in your query (wildcard),

```
 STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator )
```

Comment: This is still a valid response, OP has updated the question to indicate BigQuery is being used, that engine supports 'SPLIT' and array processing.